$f: X \to Y$ is universally injective $\Rightarrow$ For each $x\in X$ the extension $\kappa(f(x)) \to \kappa(x)$ is purely inseparable.
First let me propose assoicated question.
Q. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes. Fix $x\in X$. Assume that there exist two distinct $\kappa(f(x))$-embeddings $\psi_1, \psi_2 : \kappa(x) \to K$ of $\kappa(x)$ into an algebraically closed extension  $K$ of $\kappa(f(x))$. Then these embeddings define two distinct $Y$-morphisms $(l_1, l_1^b) , ( l_2, l_2^b) : \operatorname{Spec}K \to X$? In particular, can we choose them such that $l_1 \neq l_2 $  ( as topolocial morphism )?
As first attempt to construction, I thought
$l_1 := i_x \circ \operatorname{Spec}(\psi_1) : \operatorname{Spec}K \to \operatorname{Spec}\kappa(x) \to X$, $l_2:= i_x \circ \operatorname{Spec}(\psi_2) : \operatorname{Spec}K \to \operatorname{Spec}\kappa(x)\to X$ , where $i_x : \operatorname{Spec}\kappa(x) \to X$ is the canonical immersion. Since immersion is monomorphism,
$ i_x \circ \operatorname{Spec}(\psi_1) \neq i_x \circ \operatorname{Spec}(\psi_2)$ as scheme morphism ( $\because$ $\operatorname{Spec}(\psi_1) \neq \operatorname{Spec}(\psi_2) $ since $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are distinct ). But $ i_x \circ \operatorname{Spec}(\psi_1) = i_x \circ \operatorname{Spec}(\psi_2)$ as a topological morphism since each map sends $(0)$ to $x\in X$. This cause delicate difficulty in understanding next original question ( C.f. Gortz's Algebraic Geometry book Proposition 4.35 ) :

Proposition 4.35. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes. Then $f$ is universally injective if and only if $f$ is injective and for all $x\in X$ the extension $\kappa(f(x)) \to \kappa(x)$ induced by $f^{\sharp}_x$ is purely inseparable.

Proof.  ( $\Rightarrow$ ) Let $f$ be universally injective. Assume that $\kappa(x)$ is not purely inseparable extension of $\kappa(f(x))$ for some $x\in X$. Then there exist two distinct
$\kappa(f(x))$-embeddings of $\kappa(x)$ into an algebraically closed extension $K$ of $\kappa(f(x))$ ( Corollary B.102 ; We accept this statement ). These embeddings define two distinct $Y$-morhpisms $(l_1, l_1^b) , (l_2, l_2^b) : \operatorname{Spec}K\to X$ and hence give rise to two distinct morhpisms $\operatorname{Spec}K\to X\otimes_Y K$ of $K$-schemes. Therefore $X \otimes_Y K$ contains at least two points, and the morphism $f_{(K)} : X\otimes_Y  K \to \operatorname{Spec}K$ is not injective. QED.
Q. I am trying to understand the bold statement. I think that distinct morphisms $(\varphi_1, \varphi_1^b) , (\varphi_2 , \varphi_2^b) : \operatorname{Spec}K\to X\otimes_Y K$ are induced by the universal property of the fiber product. If so, then if $(\varphi_1 , \varphi_1^b) = (\varphi_2,\varphi_2^b)$ as scheme morphism, then $(l_1 ,l_1^b) = \pi \circ (\varphi_1, \varphi_1^b) = \pi \circ (\varphi_2, \varphi_2^b) = (l_2, l_2^b)$, where $\pi: X\otimes_Y K \to X$ is the projection, which is contradiction. So, $(\varphi_1, \varphi_1^b) \neq (\varphi_2 , \varphi_2^b)$. If $\varphi_1 \neq \varphi_2$ ( as topological morphisms ), then as in the proof, $X\otimes_Y K $ contains at least two points. But an issue that makes me stuck is, possibility of case that $\varphi_1 = \varphi_2$ and $\varphi_1^b \neq \varphi_2^b$. As I asked in the above question in the first paragraph of this post, can we choose $(l_1, l_1^b) , (l_2, l_2^b)$ such that $l_1 \neq l_2$ ? If so then we can breakthrough this difficulty.
Can anyone help?

Why do you need to choose $l_1 \neq l_2$? As you have noted, $i_x\circ \operatorname{Spec}(\psi_1) \neq i_x \circ \operatorname{Spec}(\psi_2)$, so if $p_1 : X\otimes_Y K \to X$ is the first projection, $$p_1 \circ (i_x\circ \operatorname{Spec}(\psi_1), \text{id})_Y = i_x \circ \operatorname{Spec}(\psi_1) \neq i_x \circ \operatorname{Spec}(\psi_2) = p_1 \circ (i_x\circ \operatorname{Spec}(\psi_2), \text{id})_Y$$ Thus $(i_x\circ \operatorname{Spec}(\psi_1), \text{id})_Y$ and $(i_x\circ \operatorname{Spec}(\psi_2), \text{id})_Y$ are distinct morphisms $\operatorname{Spec} K \to X\otimes_Y K$.

O.K. Btw I think that there is a delicated problem. In fact a scheme morphism $f: X\to Y$ is a pair $(f, f^b)$ where $f: |X| \to |Y|$ is a topological morphism and $f^b : \mathcal{O}Y \to f{*}\mathcal{O}_X$. So let $(\varphi_1, \varphi_1^b) := (i_x \circ \operatorname{Spec}(\psi_1) , id)_Y$ and $(\varphi_2, \varphi_2^b) := (i_x \circ \operatorname{Spec}(\psi_2) , id)_Y$. As in the proof of the Proposition 4.35 above, we want to show that $X\otimes_Y K$ contains at least two points and it suffices to show that $\varphi_1 \neq \varphi_2$ ( as topological morphism ).

But altough $(\varphi_1 ,\varphi^b) \neq (\varphi_2, \varphi_2^b)$, there is a possibility that $\varphi_1 = \varphi_2 $ and $\varphi_1^b \neq \varphi_2 ^b $. This is a point that I stuck. This case is not possible? Can we breakthrough this difficulty? Am I pointing out well? How do you think about this?
